# 90 degree belt drive

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have two axles at 90 degrees. They are 15 inches apart. each has a 2.5 inch pulley and we need 250 watts at 1000 RPM to be transmitted. WE tried round belts but they slipped too much. Thinking of timing belts with fully flanged pulleys as the life of the belts is a non issue. Does this make sense? If not ideas?

Comment: it slipped because the sheaves are too small.  Make them bigger and you will have more friction to hold the belt.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find that an ordinary vee belt will work, especially if belt wear doesn't matter. If you can, make the belt run as long as your design will accomodate; the longer the belt run, the less tendency for the vee belt to hop out of the pulleys.

Comment: Thanks. Elastic v belts look promising